# Incomplete std::string in c++ when the string contains %2C

Tags: c++, openssl, popen, stdstring

---

### **Just read my answer directly, ignore the following text...**

I am trying to read a x509 certificate using openssl CLI through C++. (Yes I know that OpenSSL has also a C API, but that is not important for my question). OpenSSL version is 1.1.0g and gcc compiler is 7.4.0

So, I want to execute the command `openssl x509 -noout -text -in certFile.cer` and get the output.

I tried to use three different C++ solutions:

- `popen()`, to retrieve the output
- `system()`, adding at the end of the command `> temp.txt` to redirect the output and then reading from it
- `system()`, using the command `openssl x509 -noout -text -in certFile.cer -out tempFile` so that I do not need to redirect the output, but the output is written to a file. Then, I read the file.

This is a piece of the code that I am using (as you can see, I also tried to add `stdbuf -o 0` to avoid buffering)

```
string execCommandAndGetOutput_withPopen(const char* cmd, int* result)
{
        std::array<char, 1024> buffer;
        std::string output;
        string cmd_unbuf;
        cmd_unbuf.append("stdbuf -o 0 ");
        cmd_unbuf.append(cmd);
        cmd_unbuf.append(" 2>&1");
        FILE* pipe = popen(cmd_unbuf.c_str(), "r");
        if (!pipe) {
              throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
        }
        while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe) != nullptr) {
              output += buffer.data();
        }
        *result = pclose(pipe);
        return output;
}

string execCommandAndGetOutput_withSystem(const char* cmd, int* result)
{
        std::string output;
        string cmd_unbuf;
        cmd_unbuf.append("stdbuf -o 0 ");
        cmd_unbuf.append(cmd);
        cmd_unbuf.append(" > /tmp/temp 2>&1");
        int  cmdResult = system(cmd_unbuf.c_str());
        std::ifstream file("/tmp/temp");
        std::string fileContent((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        remove("/tmp/temp");
        *result = cmdResult;
        return fileContent;
}
```

When using the second function, I tried to NOT remove the temporary file, and check its content, and the content is complete. So it is not a problem in the `system()` call.

In all cases, the string that I get is NOT complete. In particular it stops always at the same point, in particular in the middle of a URL, just before `%2CO`. But AFAIK, this should not be a problem, `%2` should be just a coma, html-encoded.

I tried to check the string size, and the string that I get has size `4262`, that should be far away from its maximum.

I also tried it in two machines: the first machine where I get the problem, is were all my program is installed, and where I get the error. In the second machine, my development machine, I just run some tests while developing, and I never noticed this problem, with the same input. Note that both machines are Ubuntu server 18.04.3.

So my ideas were:

- `%2` is a strange character, but it seems not
- the `string` is too big, but it seems not
- the machines are different...yes, it could be that some package is different, but the C++ libraries should be the same...I am not 100% sure but as far as I checked, they are...

I am out of ideas...someone has some suggestion? Some particular C library to check? Other ideas?

**Edit:**

Even if I would not post the certificate affected, I can post the line affected. This is the complete line:

```
URI:ldap://directory.swisssign.net/CN=DA32F949F851CC9871660CD9CEB6DB923F094BEF%2CO=SwissSign%2CC=CH?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint
```

But I get only:

```
URI:ldap://directory.swisssign.net/CN=DA32F949F851CC9871660CD9CEB6DB923F094BEF
```

I tried also adding `| grep -A 10 'X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:'` to the command (so that I could exclude that the problem was the length of the string), and the output is the same, the string is truncated. So it seems the problem is related to the character `%2C` somehow.

Any idea?

**Edit 2:**

Change subject

**Edit 3:**

I was debugging an error, that was why I was printing the string....unfortunately I used `syslog()` to print it... I suppose `2%C` was interpreted as `format`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hi Thomas, I would rather not post the certificate that gives me problem...it is a normal x509 valid certificate, but it does not belong to me...I am using the two function I provided, with the openssl command written in the question.

Anyway, as I said, it happens only in my test machine, not in my development machine, so it is difficult to have a "reproducible" example...

Maybe a different library is installed, but no idea how I could find it....

Comment: Is this a programming problem at all? You are building a command and calling it. Is this command correct and as expected. Does this command work if you call it from terminal?

Comment: yes of course. as i wrote, in the second function, i manually check the output in the file, and it is correct. so i am sure the openssl command is correct and the certificate is correct. the problem happens when i read the file where i wrote the output

Comment: also note the string is cut at the same point with both function....getting the output from popen or getting the output after having written it to a file. but i checked, the output is correct.

Comment: ps i tried more certificate and the command normally works....it is just one certificate (till now) that gives me problems...

Comment: Maybe `std::ifstream file("/tmp/temp", std::ios::binary);` would help.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that the format is binary, but you're using in some places text-based string (null-termination issues) and file handling (opening the file in text mode instead of binary mode).

Comment: thanks super and paul....i will try...even if the openssl command line interface should give a human readable output, shouldn't it?

Comment: *even if the openssl command line interface should give a human readable output* -- I guess [it depends](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/DER)

Comment: in my case it is a pem, base64 encoded certificate. and i just wanted to see the outout using the "openssl x509 -text" command. i already converted der to pem, and at this point of the code i only have pem

Comment: @super unfortunately your suggestion did not help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `%2C` in a string gives problem, make sure you are not using some function that use `format`, such as `printf` or `syslog`

In my case, while I was debugging an error, I was printing the string containing "%2C" using `syslog` and that made the confusion...